# CSS credit roll scrolling animation with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to produce a credit scrolling type effect which reads from JustGiving API and lists the donors. I am able to populate the list of donors and work with the API just fine. The problem is trying to get it scrolling up the screen.

I am using CSS animation and the effect works, but the way I have it makes the scroll only showing a certain number of the credits. I have set up the animation like:

```
@keyframes creditRoll {
  0% {
    top: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    top: -100%;
  }
}
```

And the Credits div is styled like:

```
#Credits {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            animation: creditRoll 75s linear forwards infinite;
            animation-delay: 5s;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
        }
```

I believe the `100%` refers to screen size as opposed to the div height? Is there anyway that I can get the whole div to scroll up and off the screen? It does scroll up at the minute, but stops mid way through the credits.

See https://jsfiddle.net/kao6hs2t/ for the example.

Answer (score 0):

Working with position: absolute can tricky sometimes. I would say it might be easier to manage if you give the parent div of id="Credits" a fixed height (maybe 100vh?) and probably overflow hidden as well. This way it doesn't effect the scroll bar or end up floating across content elsewhere on the page, which would also make your animation's position reliably start based on the parent div's location in the page, otherwise the position 100% could be referring to the page.

I'm not 100% sure this is the issue you're facing but hopefully it helps :)